# Select records from Oracle table where single column is unique

Tags: sql, oracle, unique

I am trying to figure out a simple and elegant way to return every row and column from a table that is uniquely identified by a certain column.

In other words.  Imagine a table has the following columns and rows in it... And I wanted all the unique duplicate ID rows...

```
id | duplicateID |Name | col1 | col2 | col3

1  |  1          |A    |B     | C    | D
2  |  1          |A    |B     | C    | D
3  |  3          |A    |B     | C    | D
4  |  3          |A    |B     | C    | D
5  |  1          |A    |B     | C    | D
6  |  5          |A    |B     | C    | D
7  |  5          |A    |B     | C    | D
8  |  6          |A    |B     | C    | D
```

I would want the all the records from ID 1, 3, 6 and 8 returned.
Because those are all the unique id's from the duplicate record column.
But I would want all the records from those rows as well.  Is there a way to 
do this simply?  I image not... So far I have written several convuluted queries with no good results.  I am no sql expert I must say.

**UPDATE**

```
1  |  1          |A    |B     | C    | D
3  |  3          |A    |B     | C    | D
6  |  5          |A    |B     | C    | D
8  |  6          |A    |B     | C    | D
```

Would be the sample result I would need.
This all for Oracle tables btw.

Comment: Please post the desired result based on your sample data.

Comment: If duplicateID 6 retrieves id 8, why doesn't duplicateID 1 retrieve id 2? `I would want the all the records from ID 1, 3, 6 and 8`

Comment: I guess I truly do want a truly unique row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use an analytic like

```
select id, duplicateid, name, col1, col2, col3
  from (select id, duplicateid, name, col1, col2, col3,
               row_number() over (partition by duplicateid order by id) rn
          from your_tab)
 where rn = 1;
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c38b1/1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question but here goes:

```
         select * from T
         inner join
         (
         select distinct duplicateID from T
         ) as V
         on T.id = V.duplicateID
```